# Can we extend the controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inheritance, controller, annotations

Can we extend the controller in Spring MVC? How should we handle the  @RequestMapping in the extended controller class? If anyone has any example please share. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what you are trying to do? Some small example would be nice

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __target specific programming problems__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: @EkanshRastogi This is required for me to implement the client specific changes in a product.

Comment: @Unihedron Thanks for your advice. I will try to be specific when I post questions in future

Answer (score 0):

If BaseController's annotation cannot be removed, then you can use **Adapter Pattern** to obtain the inheritance.

```
@Controller
public class NewController {
    // Autowired fields
    BaseController base;

    protected x toExtend() {
         base.toExtend();
         //new stuff
    }
}
```

In usual cases, either BaseController does not have `@Controller` annotation, hence common controller methods can be put inside BaseController to be extended by actual controllers